# Skeleton View issue in iOS

Tags: ios, animation

i'm trying to implement third party lib Skeleton View in my VC having table view. the data comes after an api is called. Now i want to show skeleton view in my cell content and as the data populate after an api is hit it should hide the skeleton animation. I have call the animation in cellforRow and as data comes from api before reload i end the animation but it isn't stopping the animation. How i can do that? , My code is this,

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
 let cell = activeTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "activeCell", for: indexPath) as! ActiveQuestionTVC
    let question = activeQuestionArray[indexPath.row]

        cell.showAnimatedGradientSkeleton()
        cell.closeView.isHidden = true
        cell.titleLbl.text = question.title
        var date = String()
        if let range = question.createdAt!.range(of: "T") {
            date = String(question.createdAt![(question.createdAt!.startIndex)..<range.lowerBound])
        }
        cell.dateLbl.text = "asked \(date)"
        cell.closeView.isHidden = true
        cell.bgView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        cell.bgView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.7
        cell.bgView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize.zero
        cell.bgView.layer.shadowRadius = 4
        cell.bgView.layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(rect: cell.bgView.bounds).cgPath

    return cell
    }
```

Now when data comes in api i end animation like this, `self.view.hideSkeleton()`
But my VC keep animating like this,
[image]

Comment: `cell.stopSkeleton()`? If you start the skeleton in a cell, you need to stop it there (I suppose, you didn't really show the *relevant* code, which is the animation one).

Comment: This is how i call animation cell.showAnimatedGradientSkeleton() in cellForRow delegate. Now i want it to stop when my data populate in my array after hit of api. @AlejandroIván

Comment: Again, the important code is the cell one, not your view controller's one. It's your cell that has a method for animating itself and you're not showing it, just the call to it.

Comment: Bro, i'm not getting what r u saying can u explain more? @AlejandroIván

Comment: Your example code is irrelevant, what's important is the implementation of `func showAnimatedGradientSkeleton()` inside your `UITableViewCell` subclass...

Comment: Thats what i confuse in, how i can animate cell content as my API is on hit, and hide as after it get hit. @AlejandroIván

Answer (score 0):

add this right before the return cell at the CellForRowAt

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
    cell.hideSkeleton()
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It worked For the same view controller but once you pushed to next view controller and pop up from there the skeleton view appears again and it won't hide again.